# Conway's Game of Life graphics

Tags: java, arrays, class, paintcomponent, repaint

I'm trying to make a Conway's Game of Life program, and am having trouble with the grid actually showing up on my JFrame.  When I write the code like the following, my paintComponent works perfectly:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class AutomataTheoryAssignmentTesting {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   RandomTrues grid = new RandomTrues(); // I know these two lines don't affect the grid added
   grid.neighborAnalysis();              // to my JPanel, hence why I'm trying to find an alternative solution
   MakeTotalPanel frame = new MakeTotalPanel();
   frame.setTitle("Game of Life");
   frame.setSize(620, 620);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class MakeTotalPanel extends JFrame {

   MakeTotalPanel() {
      setLayout(new GridLayout(30, 30, 2, 2));
      for(int i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
         add(new RandomTrues());
      }
   }
}
```

However, in order to fix the dilemma I wrote in the comment in the code, I know I need to    do something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class AutomataTheoryAssignmentTesting {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

   MakeTotalPanel frame = new MakeTotalPanel();
   frame.setTitle("Game of Life");
   frame.setSize(620, 620);
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
   frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}

class MakeTotalPanel extends JFrame {

   RandomTrues grid = new RandomTrues();

   MakeTotalPanel() {
      grid.neighborAnalysis();
      setLayout(new GridLayout(30, 30, 2, 2));
      for(int i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
         add(grid);
      }
   }
}
```

However, when I do this, only a small square at the upper right hand corner actually paints.  The rest of my code is as follows... Thank you in advance!

```
class RandomTrues extends JPanel {

   boolean[][] gridvalues;
   int rowcounter = 0;
   int colcounter = 0;

   public RandomTrues() {

      gridvalues = new boolean[30][30];
      Random generator = new Random();
      double b;

      for(int i=0; i<30; i++) {
         for(int j=0; j<30; j++) {
            b = generator.nextDouble() * 100;
            if (b <= 62)
               gridvalues[i][j] = true;
            else
               gridvalues[i][j] = false;
         }
      }  
   }

      // reading the values of the grid and marking to change or not to change
      void neighborAnalysis() {

      int g;
      int h;
      boolean[][] change = new boolean[30][30];
      for(int k=0; k<30; k++) {
         for(int l=0; l<30; l++) {
            change[k][l] = false;
         }

      for(g=0; g<30; g++) {
         for(h=0; h<30; h++) {
            if(g==0) {
               if(h==0) {
                  if(gridvalues[g][h] == true) {
                     if(gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false) {
                        change[g][h]=true;
                     }
                  }
               }
               else if(h==29) {
                  if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                     if(gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false) {
                        change[g][h]=true;
                     }
                  }
               }
               else {
                  if(gridvalues[g][h]==false) {
                     if(gridvalues[g+1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h+1]==true && gridvalues[g][h-1]==true) {
                        change[g][h]=true;
                     }
                  }
                  else if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                     if((gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false) || (gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false) || (gridvalues[g][h+1]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false)) {
                        change[g][h]=true;
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
            if(g==29) {
               if(h==0) {
                  if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                     if(gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false) {
                        change[g][h]=true;
                     }
                  }
               }
               else if(h==29) {
                  if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                 if(gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
           }
           else {
              if(gridvalues[g][h]==false) {
                 if(gridvalues[g-1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h+1]==true && gridvalues[g][h-1]==true) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
              else if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                 if((gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false) || (gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false) || (gridvalues[g][h+1]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false)) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
           }
        }
        else if(g<29 && g>0) {
           if(h==0) {
              if(gridvalues[g][h]==false) {
                 if(gridvalues[g-1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h+1]==true && gridvalues[g+1][h]==true) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
              else if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                 if((gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g+1][h]==false) || (gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false) || (gridvalues[g][h+1]==false && gridvalues[g+1][h]==false)) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
           }
           if(h==29) {
              if(gridvalues[g][h]==false) {
                 if(gridvalues[g-1][h]==true && gridvalues[g+1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h-1]==true) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
              else if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                 if((gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false) || (gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g+1][h]==false) || (gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false)) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
           }
           else if(h<29 && h>0) {
              if(gridvalues[g][h]==false) {
                 if((gridvalues[g-1][h]==true && gridvalues[g+1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h+1]==true)||(gridvalues[g+1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h+1]==true && gridvalues[g][h-1]==true)||(gridvalues[g][h+1]==true && gridvalues[g][h-1]==true && gridvalues[g-1][h]==true)||(gridvalues[g][h-1]==true && gridvalues[g+1][h]==true && gridvalues[g-1][h]==true)) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
              else if(gridvalues[g][h]==true) {
                 if((gridvalues[g-1][h]==false && gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false)||(gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g][h+1]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false)||(gridvalues[g][h+1]==false && gridvalues[g][h-1]==false && gridvalues[g-1][h]==false)||(gridvalues[g][h-1]==false && gridvalues[g+1][h]==false && gridvalues[g-1][h]==false)) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
                 else if(gridvalues[g-1][h]==true && gridvalues[g+1][h]==true && gridvalues[g][h+1]==true && gridvalues[g][h-1]==true) {
                    change[g][h]=true;
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }

  // changing the grid values

  g = 0;
  h = 0;

  for(g=0; g<30; g++) {
     for(h=0; h<30; h++) {
        if(change[g][h]==true) {
           gridvalues[g][h] = !gridvalues[g][h];
           change[g][h] = false;
        }
     }
  }
 }
}

   //paint component
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      super.paintComponent(g);
      g.drawRect(1, 1, 30, 30);
      if(gridvalues[rowcounter][colcounter] == false) {
         g.setColor(Color.RED);
         g.fillRect(1, 1, 30, 30);
      }
      else if(gridvalues[rowcounter][colcounter] == true) {
         g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
         g.fillRect(1, 1, 30, 30);
      }
      rowcounter = rowcounter + 1;
      colcounter = colcounter + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: This article might be of interest to you -- [John Conway’s Game of Life in Java Swing](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=504)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
  grid.neighborAnalysis();
  setLayout(new GridLayout(30, 30, 2, 2));
  for(int i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
     add(grid);
  }
```

You are trying to add the same component, grid multiple times to your GUI, and this won't work since a component can only be displayed in one container.

Your logic seems faulty since the RandomTrues class already holds a 30 by 30 grid, and so adding it once to the JFrame and not 900 times should be adequate, assuming that RandomTrues works.

If this were my program, I would try to separate the program logic from its GUI, or put in another way, to separate out the model from the view. The view would be a JPanel that held a grid of cells, which could be JPanels if desired, and with methods for allowing outside classes (the control) to set the state of these cells.